# clear history after logout and redirect back to login up on clicking back button in browser just like gmail, facebook

Tags: browser, struts2, try-catch, browser-history

Hi Friends i developed web application when user logout i am clearing the session and redirecting to the logout page. the problem is when user click back button of browser it shows the previous page content, i want to redirect user to login page after he click back button of browser.
I tried no-catch, no-store, expire-0 all the methods included in jsp and also setting through action methods but not working.

**when i google it i found that the content it is showing is history,in some article they say to redirect through https instead of http it will over look on all that so can anybody give suggestion i need it desperately. also i wonder how these gmail, facebook fellows have overcome that one.
I am open to suggestion please tell me exactly how to overcome that one because in my application it perform some creditcard transactions**

Answer (score 1):

Can you use JavaScript to control the redirecting? If so, you could use:

```
window.location.replace(path/to/page);
```

to replace the confirmation page with the log out page in the browser history. If the user clicks the back button, they are redirected to the page before the confirmation page.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into head. What is happening is that the browser is storing the page in cache; it is not actually reloading the page.

This code tells the browser to not cache the page (therefore request the page again, triggering your redirect code)

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"> <!-- tells browser not to cache -->
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"> <!-- says that the cache expires 'now' -->
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"> <!-- says not to use cached stuff, if there is any -->
```

Comment: i already tried it by including that in the all jsp page but still if u press back button it will display the previous page.